# Using SevenZipSharp to extract bzip2 file add a needless tar extension to file, and can't get right archive informations?

Tags: c#, 7zip, bzip2, sevenzipsharp

Using following code to extracting a bzip2 file to a specified directory:

```
string[] archive_files = null;
using (SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor extrator = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(source_file));
{
    extrator.ExtractArchive(dest_directory);
    archive_files = extrator.ArchiveFileNames.ToArray();
}
```

, however I got a file in target directory which has .tar adds on it, the file is correct if I remove last extension. but archive files returns from extrator is "[no name]" instead of archive file name, It seems it doesn't get the archive file infos from the source file. Is these a bug, any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that `extrator.ArchiveFileNames` is empty or null, or that it contains the literal string `"[no name]"`?

Comment: It contains a string array with one empty string.